# How to override injected Bean inside ViewModel in UnitTests with stubbing on Koin Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, viewmodel, koin

I am writing UnitTests for ViewModel/StateMachine (using MVI pattern). The ViewModel has API bean injected inside (built with Retrofit)

```
class UserViewModel(
    private val API: API
)

object UserModule {
    fun get(): Module {
        return module {
            viewModel { UserViewModel(api = get()) }
        }
    }
}

object NetworkModule {
    fun get(): Module {
        return module {
            ... // various retrofit Beans
            single{ Api(retrofit = get()) }
        }
    }
}
```

This works in my application, but when UnitTesting I was to stub the responses from `API`, in one test stub it with error, in another stub it with mock response, so having some `MockNetworkModule, MockFailingNetworkModule` with the same interface seems like an overkill and it's not so on-the-fly as having mock data ready in test code block.

This is how I try to stub the calls, but **it still uses the old implementation and does network calls**

```
class UserTest : KoinTest {
    @get:Rule
    val schedulers = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()

    private val viewModel: UserViewModel by inject()

    @Before
    fun before() {
        startKoin {
            modules(
                listOf(
                    UserModule.get(),
                    NetworkModule.get()
                )
            )
        }
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        stopKoin()
    }
}
```

My Tests are written like this (similar to what I read from Koin documentation):

```
@Test
fun `user test passing`() {
    val mockUserData = UserData("name", "surname")

    declareMock<Api> {
        given(this.getUserData()).willReturn { Single.just(mockUserData) }
    }

    viewModel.refresh() // calls api.getUserData() inside

    ... expecting mockUserData but getting real api call
}

@Test
fun `user test failing`() {
    declareMock<Api> {
        given(this.getUserData()).willReturn { Single.error(Exception("mock")) }
    }

    viewModel.refresh() // calls api.getUserData() inside

    ... expecting exception but getting real api call
}
```

I Also tried `declareMock<UserViewModel>{ given(this.api.getUserData()} ...` but had `NullPointerException` on `this.api`.

**TL;DR** How to properly stub already injected bean inside viewModel for UnitTesting on-the-fly